# c#- Customize MessageBox

Tags: c#, winforms, messagebox

I want to create `MessageBox` with Button `Yes`, `No` and `Close` (X).

If I use `MessageBoxButtons.YesNo` then the button `Close` (X) is disabled.

If I use `MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel` then the button `Close`(X) is enabled but I want to remove button `Cancel`.

Can anyone help me to solve this problem but don't create new `Form` as `MessageBox`?

Thanks everyone for reading!

Comment: Did you tried `MessageBoxButtons.YesNo | MessageBoxButtons.Close`? Don't know if it works, just giving some ideas.

Comment: You can crete your own MessageBox with adding new Form.

Comment: the standard MessageBox will always combine Close(X) with the CancelButton (which has the same effect). If you want only one, you will have to create your own messagebox.